Why am I getting ERROR:root:java.lang.NullPointerException when I am trying to run beam pipeline on flink cluster?
I am trying to run a simple beam pipeline on a locally hosted flink cluster but I am getting errors on doing that. I have tried everything I can find on the internet.
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import apache_beam.transforms.window as window

def run():
    options = PipelineOptions([
        "--runner=FlinkRunner",
        "--flink_master=localhost:8081",
        "--environment_type=EXTERNAL",
        "--environment_config=localhost:50000"
    ])

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (p
            | 'Create words' >> beam.Create(['to be or not to be'])
            | 'Split words' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda words: words.split(' '))
            | 'Write to file' >> WriteToText('testproject.txt')
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()

This is the code I am trying to run and I am getting these errors :

(env) shivakhatri@Shivas-Air beam-starter-python % python3.8 app.py WARNING:root:Waiting for grpc channel to be ready at localhost:55999. WARNING:root:Waiting for grpc channel to be ready at localhost:55999. WARNING:root:Waiting for grpc channel to be ready at localhost:55999. WARNING:root:Waiting for grpc channel to be ready at localhost:55999. ERROR:root:java.lang.NullPointerException Traceback (most recent call last):   File "app.py", line 23, in <module>     run()   File "app.py", line 16, in run     (p   File "/Users/shivakhatri/Documents/work/beam-starter-python/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 601, in _exit_     self.result.wait_until_finish()   File "/Users/shivakhatri/Documents/work/beam-starter-python/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/portable_runner.py", line 614, in wait_until_finish     raise self._runtime_exception RuntimeError: Pipeline BeamApp-shivakhatri-0405201752-c62cb18a_fd177a56-ec3e-448a-a46a-4530de13702b failed in state FAILED: java.lang.NullPointerException zsh: segmentation fault  python3.8 app.py (env) shivakhatri@Shivas-Air beam-starter-python %


Have you checked https://lists.apache.org/thread/g3kz7d6w0dhpvyr0yw6y33w4pmjwq6wy? You do not need run the expansion service since you do not use cross-lang.
